# Alias ou clone de tabela MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela no `MySQL` que está com um nome errado, essa tabela já é usada por muitas aplicações, por isso não seria muito simples renomeá-la.

Existe alguma forma de se criar um `alias` para essa tabela ou um `clone` para que tudo que for feito em uma seja feito na outra?

Com isso as aplicações novas já utilizariam o nome correto e aos poucos eu consigo atualizar as aplicações antigas.

Comment: Não sei se teria como criar um clone, mas você poderia criar uma nova tabela com todos os atributos e criar um gatilho(trigger) que ao inserir na tabela do MySQL que está com nome errado, automaticamente insere na nova tabela.

Answer (score 3):

A melhor solução seria criar uma segunda tabela com estrutura idêntica a primeira e trabalhar com trigger. Sempre que houver inserção, atualização ou exclusão na tabela 1, atualizará na tabela 2. O inverso também precisa ocorrer, afinal as novas aplicações vão trabalhar só com a tabela 2, logo suas modificações precisão ser refletidas na tabela 1.